# Detect Another Application on Browser Window (including percentage overlap)

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, browser, activex

Is there a way to detect if an application (say a chat client or msword) is on top of my browser window.

One way is to check for focus. But that does not absolutely say that another program is on top of the "view-able" area of the browser with respect to complete screen.

What if the complete browser is viewable but the focus is on the word document/chat client.

Edit:

Found a sample demo from a company which does this http://www.spider.io/vStp83jg6/

Comment: The browser won't be able to get that info. If the operating system allows it; then you can run an AIR app on the local machine which can get that info via a NativeProcess/NativeExtension. The AIR app can communicate w/ the browser app using a LocalConnection.

Comment: That would need installation of another application on the OS. Which is not feasible in my needs :(

Comment: If browsers were able to do this, I'd replace mine in a hurry.

Comment: theoretically its a privacy violation. But there are companies which claim to be doing this and I am trying to figure out how they do it.

Comment: No browser can do that. But you can use full screen in Flash to ensure there is nothing above.

Comment: This is probably as close as you can get inside the browser's security sandbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

Comment: http://www.spider.io/vStp83jg6/

Comment: Did you watch the Spider.io video where they explain how it works: http://www.spider.io/viewability/

Comment: I had figured out all those FPS related throttling long ago. The part about external app on top is perplexing.

Comment: I think when the browser is hidden by another app, the rendering optimizations kick in and FPS for the non visible regions of the page drop. If they detect this in several regions like the 4 corners of the visible viewport and the center of the page they can safely assume that the app is hidden by another external app.

Comment: FPS kicks in with Flash if element is hidden by browser actions:
- Browser Minimizes
- Flash element is not seen in the UI (hidden by another element).

It does not kick in when we put an application on top of it. 

This is based on my expts

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this requires flash or any plugin, in order to be effective this has to be based on CSS and Javascript.

The security sandbox of the browser prevents accessing this information from the operating system.

The only thing that they can be doing consistently across browsers is to **detect some sort of side effect** of the fact that the browser window is hidden by another window.

One of the side effects that can be detected is if browser **rendering optimizations** for painting elements have kicked in or not.

According to the spider.io [viewability](http://spider.io/viewability) video, they are already detecting if an add is visible based on browser rendering optimizations detection.

If an add is not visible, then for that section of the page rendering optimizations kick in and the rendering of that section of the page will become slower, in order to save memory and CPU resources, and speed up the rendering of the visible portion of the page.

This same technique could be used to detect if a browser window is hidden or not.

If they detect that rendering optimizations are ongoing in several regions like the 4 corners of the visible viewport and the center of the page they can safely assume that the app is hidden by another external app, or calculate an estimation for the percentage overlap.

They don't say how they do it in detail, but as it's based on speed measurements it might be something like this:

**One way that could be used for detecting if another window is hiding the browser:**

Create a small invisible CSS3 or Javascript based animation that animates invisible elements in different parts of the page. The animations should not affect the performance of the page and can be started/stopped at will.

Measure the timings of the animation at page startup, and take an average. If the page get's hidden by another OS window, then the rendering optimizations kick in and the time that the animation takes to run is longer.

Check here a [browser API](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/) to detect the start and stop of CSS3 animations, this could be a way to implement this.

Comment: Can you share some code sample to evaluate this, I will try the same from my end too

Answer (score 2):

1. Commercial web traffic data harvested by company such as Alexa. Is performed by installed software, such as toolbars. And tracks the users activity, programs, windows open.... everything... (with consent)
2. Controversial answer, it does the above without consent (spyware?)

Note the key point of the above 2 method. is that the data comes from a sample of computers in which the software is installed. Not every visitor of the site (unless visiting the site inserts the spyware)

By having custom software installed. They can get around all the respective browser related restrictions / security.

Perhaps more can be found by providing information on the companies that claim to do this?

Comment: I don't understand how this answer relates to the question. What does web traffic data harvesting have to do with knowing if another program is blocking the window?

Comment: @Reboog711 Cause some of them: harvest everything you are doing. Including all the programs currently open, their location, and the mouse location "heat-map". etc. etc... Knowing the window overlapping and blocking is quite an easy feat once you have all that data.